# Assigning pages based on RoleId on front end in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

On my master page, I have:

```
if (UserRole == 1)
{
}
else
{                      
}
```

where 1 is for admin, so he can see user management page. But if it is 0, that is not admin then user management page will not be shown to him. How can I do this on front end?

Comment: You can have an element/placeholder/user control or whatever contains your data and set `whateverId.Visible = UserRole == 1;`.

Comment: i have to make User management.aspx page visible for admin but not for other user

Comment: Please provide more details as to what your problem is. You probably don't want that logic in the masterpage. You can put it in the `User management.aspx` page itself, though you could even secure this in the web.config.

Comment: in master page i am fetching user id from windows authentication.then i am fetching the role for that particular user based on user id from database.then on my master page i am checking that if that user id is 1 ,then show him a specific set of aspx pages or if it is 0 show him some other specific set of pages